# Smaller drops in fluid simulation

Tags: physics, fluid-simulation

I want to make a simple straight fountain. I used fluid physics - cube inside the domain is inflow type (Z velocity: 2). It looks like this:

[image]

As it can be seen fountain is spurting with "compact" water, which looks more like gunk than water. How to make smaller sprays and drops (which is forming water mist as it can be seen in a photo below)? Changing "real word size" to low amount helped a bit, but not too much.

[image]

Comment: Higher resolution makes drops smaller.

Comment: I'd do that small drops with particle systems