# How can I scale my fluid simulation so that the droplets aren't so large?

Tags: physics, fluid-simulation

I am trying to become competent with Fluid Domains, trying out various tutorial stuff.  Thought I would try to build a simple fountain to learn more about Inflow and Obstacles.  Here is the render:

https://www.flickr.com/photos/rootlessagrarian/32201697302

[image]

I figured out the timeline issue (I think) i.e. it seems that the fluid sim runs for X seconds (its own internal time) and I need to set X equal to the duration of my clip if I don't want a slo-mo effect.

However, I think there's a scale issue that I don't yet understand:  the water droplets seem awfully large and blobby.  I kept my fluid domain smallish as recommended by just about everyone, because I didn't want huge render times; and I thought that the .5 meter size shown in the fluid domain parameters indicated how the fluid was scaled *within* the domain.  But my finished render looks more like macro photography, like a very tiny model of a fountain.

Can someone unconfuse me on this point?  How can I scale the fluid physics so that droplets, ripples, and other behaviours look right for a given scale of object (like an ornamental fountain maybe 2 or 3 feet tall)?

Comment: sorry, it was an avi file and too large to upload.  guess I should have just posted one frame.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After Ray M rewrote my Question headline, the changed wording caused the site search engine to find a similar -- duplicate, actually -- question ([Smaller drops in fluid simulation](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/61142/smaller-drops-in-fluid-simulation?rq=1)) and this led me to the answer:

*Higher resolution will make droplets smaller.*

I have therefore done a 2-hour Bake at resolution 200, and am awaiting a multi-hour render to see the result.  I think I'm learning that realistic Fluid Sim is very, very expensive in CPU time. [btw thanks Ray :-)]